# Как получить список всех пользователей сервера discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я уже пытался разными способами, по тем либо иным причинам код не срабатывает.
[image]
Пункты нужные проставил.

Этот код выводит только бота

```
@bot.command()
async def user_list(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(тут айди сервера)
    for member in guild.members:
        print(guild.members)
```

Вот вывод:

```
[<Member id=айди name='testbot1' discriminator='дискриминатор' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=айди name='название сервера' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=23>>]
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Намерения включили, а [**выдать**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) их не забыли?

Comment: @denisnumb Я думал что я их выдал, но оказалось я неправильно написал слово Intents, спасибо